# How to get output of psql select command when I run docker exec?

Tags: docker

docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID psql -U postgres -d DB -c "select 1" > /dev/null 2>&1

How do I get the output of select 1 in the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
docker exec CONTAINER_ID bash -c "psql -U postgres -d DB -c \"select 1\" "
```